# Save Google Form via Android App

Tags: android, date, checkbox, radio-button, google-forms

I created an Android app where users can save data to Google Spreedsheet using Google Form. I followed [this](http://codesmith.in/post-data-google-drive-sheet-through-mobile-app/) POST which I found is very useful for me, but I'm having some trouble.  I'm not able to save data of `RadioButton` , `CheckBox`, `Date`....To upload data we need Key-Value pair.. for `TextView` its easy to find as ID field is using Inspect Element, But for `RadioButton` , `CheckBox` there are multiple IDs.. How to set data for that..
Can anyone please tell me, how to make it possible??

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet which is causing the problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Hi Akshay!!! I too followed the same post which you follwed and facing same problem. Could you please help me if you got a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to work with Radion Buttons, but as there are number of Id's for  different radio buttons. So i just opted for "Choose from a List" in google form. There in list you will have one Id for spinner and multiple options. Take the Entry_Id from form and attached with your spinner id. Here is the code

```
 s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
 list.add("Male");
    list.add("Female");
    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    ad.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(ad);
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            result = list.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you selected:" + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

And in Your Post() method add this lines

```
gender = String.valueOf(s.getSelectedItem());  String data ="entry_1008323309=" + URLEncoder.encode(gender);
```

Hope this Will help you out.